# Birth-death model involving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out the following problem:

Consider the birth-death model for a female population: $\frac{dF}{dt} = bF − dF$, where $b$ is
the birthrate of females and $d$ is the death rate of females. In each part fully explain changing the model to incorporate a new assumption/ remove an assumption from the original model.

The part I'm stuck on is this:

What if death rates substantially vary depending on the age of the individual?

It says that the incorporation of the above does not need to result in a first-order homogenous linear differential equation. It can be multiple differential equations.

The progress I've made is that $F_{t+1}=F_t+bF_t-\sum_{i=0}^t d_{t-i}F_i$. But this is only a difference equation, not a differential equation.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If the death rate depends on the age, then $d=d(a)$ is now a distribution of death rates depending on the age $a$ of the individual. We then have the number of individuals $F$ of age $a$ at time $t$ described by a function $F(a,t)$ of two variables. The model (often called age-structured population models), then becomes a PDE. The simplest example of this is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Foerster_equation).

Comment: Is there any way to have an ordinary differential equation instead of a partial differential equation?

Comment: If the death rate depends on the individual's age, and you want to capture the entire population in a single equation, the population will necessarily be a function of age. Every age-structured model I have ever seen has been a PDE. I suppose if there is some cutoff age, or way to put individuals in age groups, where the difference in death rate of individuals within an age group are not significant for the modeler's purposes, then you could create a model with distinct ODEs for each age group.

Comment: I am not an expert; I just used to work with population models as an undergrad. My main advice is to look into "age-structured population models". This is the buzz word that will give you examples of how people incorporate age-dependent death/birth rates into these models.